# forecast package versions different result

Tags: r, azure-virtual-machine, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using R forecast package auto.arima() function, testing it against a predictable sine wave time series. When I run the R code on local machine in R studio, I get a significantly different output to running exactly the same code with the same source data as in azure ML. The only difference I can see is that azure has an older version of forecast package 5.4 whereas i have downloaded the latest version on local machine 5.9. (Interestingly the older version in azure ML correctly forecasts future values, the newer version predicts an attenuating amplitude, which is incorrect).

My question then is for anyone who may know why a function's behaviour would change so significantly between package versions, which strikes me as very strange. Or am I missing something here? I am new to both R and azure ML..

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Just to verify that the only difference is the package version, try to run the code on your local machine with the old version of `forcast`. You can get the old version using `install_version` from the `devtools` package.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the function auto.arima many times in both local R (RStudio) and AML, I always get the same results. AML is good for deployment but not easy for debugging, so usually I tested my code locally first. I suspect the difference may be due to the different versions of the forecast package, or different settings of the function auto.arima.

To make an apple-to-apple comparison,  I would suggest:
1) use the same version of the forecast package
2) use the same parameter setting
3) use the same input data.